# Swagger "No operations defined in spec!" when deploy on server (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, swagger

In local, Swagger works perfectly well. However, when I deploy the production version on my remote machine, Swagger still shows up on my url / api-docs but throws the error "No operations defined in spec!" and no longer displays the routes, only the Schemas.
I cannot identify the source of the error.

[In local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrCjl.png)

[On the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rVUK.png)

And I have this in Swagger configuration:

```
const swaggerOptions = {
    swaggerDefinition: {
        openapi: "3.0.0",
        info: {
            version: "1.0.0",
            title: "Kourier API",
            description: "Kourier API Documentation",
            contact: {
                name: "Amazing Developer"
            },
        },
        servers: [
            {url: "http://localhost:3000/"}
        ],
    },
    apis: [
        "./Api/Models/Swagger/User.js",
        "./Api/Models/Swagger/ResetPassword.js",
        "./Api/routes/user/index.js",
        "./Api/routes/reset-password/index.js",
        "./Api/routes/template/index.js",
        "./Api/Models/Swagger/Template.js",
        "./Api/Models/Swagger/Preview.js"
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your `server address` to the parameter `swaggerDefinition.server.url` instead of using `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: It just changes the url of the server that will be used to test routes. Swagger being on this server, "localhost: 3000" is the correct address.

Comment: have you found an answer to this issue?